# How many meteorites have been found some place other than Earth? Where is an authoritative list maintained?

Tags: mars, meteorite, resource-request

**Backgound:**

After seeing this [tweet](https://twitter.com/WierzchosKacper/status/1232460436634656769) by astronomer Kacper Wierzchoś about our not-so-new but at least newly-discovered "mini-moon" I scrolled down and saw the tweeted image below.

The object is the known short-period comet [114P/Wiseman–Skiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/114P/Wiseman%E2%80%93Skiff). The article goes on to say:

> Comet 114P/Wiseman–Skiff is believed to have been the parent body of the [first meteor photographed from Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy_on_Mars)

**Context:**

and *that article* says

> As on Earth, when a meteor is large enough to actually impact with the surface (without burning up completely in the atmosphere), it becomes a meteorite. The first known meteorite discovered on Mars (and the third known meteorite found someplace other than Earth) was [Heat Shield Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_Shield_Rock). The first and the second ones were found on the moon by the Apollo missions.

This doesn't mention [Egg Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_Rock) (as discussed in [Who discovered “Egg Rock”? The Curiosity rover or people?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24660/12102)) so we know that there must be at least four meteorites found some place other than Earth.

But I don't yet know how many there are in total

**Question:** How many meteorites have been found some place other than Earth? Where is an authoritative tally or listing actively maintained?

from [EarthSky](http://earthsky.org/space/curiosity-meteorite-mars-october-30-2016), credit NASA/JPL/[ASU](http://redplanet.asu.edu/?p=20977), captions "October 30, 2016 image via Curiosity rover on Mars" (click for larger size):

[image: "Egg Rock" meteorite on Mars] [image: "Egg Rock" meteorite on Mars] [image: "Egg Rock" meteorite on Mars]

Comment: [Mars](https://www.space.com/26533-curiosity-mars-rover-meteorite-photos.html), [impact craters found on Venus](https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/exploring-the-planets/online/solar-system/venus/craters.cfm) (possible explanation as Venus atmosphere is so dense, they break up creating clusters and craters.

Comment: Statistically, if they found a basketball meteorite, they could have passed 50 golfball ones and 1000 pea sized ones. Check "tour of moon in 4k" one crater has a 100m rock on the central mound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I managed to find such list (and even more): [Meteoritical Bulletin](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meteor/metbull.php).

You can search for every location where at least one meteorite was found (including Mars and Moon). You can also choose among many other useful options. I found 15 on Mars and 2 on Moon, so I believe there are 17 extraterrestrial meteorites found.

Comment: Cool, this is wonderful! I see only "Egg rock" in the link, does this mean that there is only one meteorite found on Mars that's listed in the whole catalog, or does it list others? The first part of the question is "How many meteorites have been found some place other than Earth?" is it possible to figure this out by getting the total number and subtracting the number found on Earth?

Comment: @uhoh Oh, sorry, I pasted the link while I was looking at some of them. I corrected the link, but you need to select Mars and click Search.

Comment: So about 15 on Mars? *Excellent!*