# Observed meteors on Venus?

Tags: asteroids, venus, meteor

In an [article on Venus by JPL from 1996](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA00477) I read

> Due to the dense Venusian atmosphere, primary impact craters of less than a 3 kilometer (2 mile) diameter are nonexistent.

I am now wondering whether there is somewhere a comprehensive list of (other) directly observed strikes of incoming rocks  on Venus e.g. by atmospheric anomalities?

Side-question: What minimal size must an object entering Venus' have in order to reach the ground and/or leave an obserable trace on the surface?

#### References

- [Wikipedia List of craters on Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_craters_on_Venus) would allow to compile a size distribution of all incoming objects larger than a certain size.
- [Meteor size and frequency distribution for Earth vs. moon or other planets?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40591/meteor-size-and-frequency-distribution-for-earth-vs-moon-or-other-planets)
- [Britannica on Meteor vs. meteoride vs. meteorite](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-a-meteoroid-a-meteor-and-a-meteorite)
- [How many meteorites have been found some place other than Earth? Where is an authoritative list maintained?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35309)

Comment: See my comment in this question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35309/how-many-meteorites-have-been-found-some-place-other-than-earth-where-is-an-aut

Comment: @NilayGhosh From your comment I conclude: The numbers of craters is only an upper bound for the number of incoming objects on planets with a dense atmosphere as the latter breaks up meteors which potentially form multiple overlapping craters.